# Sort the arguments and insert each word into an array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

So let's say I have these arguments: "aword1 bword dword zword aword2"

I must take them and insert them into an array of strings like this:

```
arrayofstrings[0][] = aword1 aword2
arrayofstrings[1][] = bword
arrayofstrings[2][] = null/nothing
arrayofstrings[3][] = dword
...
arrayofstrings[25][] = zword
```

I already know how to do this but it's not elegant.

My solution: check each word in args for it's first letter (26 if's or 26 cases) and increment counters in a 26 integer array so I can know how much space I must allocate and check and copy each word into the [][]arrayofstrings.

How can I do it without 26 if's or cases? Much appreciated. In case you didn't notice I'm new to c#(coming from c++, vb).

ps: my alphabet contains 26 letters.

Later edit:

Here's my sample code (just for you to get an ideea of what I want):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab4LineComanda
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[][] ArrayOfStrings = new string[25][];
            int[] counters = new int[26];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                if (args[i].First() == 'a')
                    counters[0]++;
                if (args[i].First() == 'b')
                    counters[1]++;
                //if's for each letter which I don't feel like doing
                if (args[i].First() == 'z')
                   counters[25]++;
            }
            Array.Sort(args);

            ArrayOfStrings[0] = new string[counters[0]];
            ArrayOfStrings[1] = new string[counters[1]];
            for (int i = 0; i < counters[0]; i++)
                ArrayOfStrings[0][i] = args[i];
            //again, for each letter i must do this, which, again, I don't feel like doing(there must be better way)

        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how many words that start with 'a' are(if any). That goes for every letter.

I must use a string[][] for education purposes. I used the "c++" tag because to me it's more like a logic problem and not a language specific problem but it's my bad.

Sorry for confuses, it's hard for me to explain exactly what I want because English is hard(for me) :).

Comment: So which language are we working in here? C++ or C#? Pick one. Please also show your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in 3 lines:

```
IList<IList<string>> allMyStrings = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 26)
                                    .Select(x => new List<string>()).ToArray();
foreach (var arg in "aword1 bword dword zword aword2".Split(' '))
    allMyStrings[arg[0] - 'a'].Add(arg);
```

Instead of a `string[][]`, I used a `List<string>[]`, so that the lists inside will resize themselves as needed. And for calculating which list to add the string to, I use `arg[0] - 'a'`, which calculates the difference in the `char` values between the first letter of the argument and the character `a`. It's not general code, in that it will not work correctly if any of the arguments don't start with a letter from `a-z`, but it works for your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that in character table all the letters from `a` to `z` are going in sequential order. So you can allocate `List<List<String>>` and get the index to add by `ord('a') - ord(firstChar)`.

Comment: It is not Python for ord. May be (int)'a'?

Comment: Actually, it just for showing the idea - it is not a real code.